# How to restore tensorflow model once but use multiple times?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I would like to be able to restore a tensorflow model once in my program, but use it for multiple inputs. Currently I have

```
for i in range(100):
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        saver.restore(sess, 'C:/model.ckpt')
        y_pred = sess.run(tf.argmax(y, 1), feed_dict={X: test_current}
```

However, I would like to be able to do something like

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver.restore(sess, 'C:/model.ckpt')
    for i in range(100):
        y_pred = sess.run(tf.argmax(y, 1), feed_dict={X: test_current}
```

But I get an error, if I type that so could I get some help?

Comment: Your code looks correct to me. What error did you get?

Comment: I actually don't get errors now. It was due to the fact that I ran a certain part of it in a function.